# set a cookie from sub-domain a to a different sub-domain b

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, subdomain, single-sign-on

I am trying to set a cookie from `http://srv-qa-aaa.nipendo.il`

to `http://srv-qa-bbb.nipendo.il` like this `Set-Cookie:PAuth=12345=; domain=nipendo.il; path=/; HttpOnly`

It does not work. The cookie is not being set unless I add the `srv-qa-aaa` prefix to the domain attribute, and that is not what I want.

I have also tried to play around with chrome dev tools and set a cookie manually like this.

[image: example of setting a cookie from JavaScript from one sub-domain to another with no success]

but with no success.

I think is might have something to do with the fact that I am using machine name in the domain., but I am not sure. This is my dev environment and I want to test it before I uploading to production.

does anyone have an idea what could be wrong in the scenario?

**UPDATE:**

Ok I have tired to set a cookie on a real domain, that is not a domain made by my private DNS server on the office network. **It worked**, the cookie has been set successfully. Now my question is how does chrome or IE knows that the `srv-qa-bbb.nipendo.il` is not a public domain and what does it meter any way? is there no way to set a cookie on a private local env?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a starting dot to your domain, i.e. use:

```
Set-Cookie:PAuth=12345=; domain=.nipendo.il; path=/; HttpOnly
```

The older cookie RFC required this in order to apply cookie for all subdomains. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109#section-4.3.2 for details.